# How to optimize a large recursive task concurrently

Tags: go

i have a chron task to perform the best way in Golang.

1. I need to store big data from web service in JSON in `sellers`
2. After saving these `sellers` in a database, i need to browse another large JSON webservice with `sellersID` parameter to save to another table named `customers`.
3. Each `customer` has an initial state, if this state has changed from the data of the webservice *(n°2)* i need to store the difference in another table `changes` to have a history of changes.
4. Finally, if the change is equal to our conditions I perform another task.

#### My current operation

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
action.FetchSellers() // fetch large JSON and stort in sellers table ~2min

sellers := action.ListSellers()
for _, s := range sellers {
    wg.Add(1)
    go action.FetchCustomers(&wg, s) // fetch multiple large JSON and stort in customers table and store notify... ~20sec
}
wg.Wait()
```

- The first difficulty with this code is that I do not control the number of calls to the webservice.
- The second is that the `action.FetchCustomers` function does a lot of work that I think can be done in a concurrency way.
- The third difficulty is that I can not resume where an error has occurred in case of errors.

I need to run this code every hour so it needs to be well built, currently it works but not in the best way.
I think that considering the use of Worker Pools in Go like this example [Go by Example: Worker Pools](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools) But I have trouble conceiving it

Comment: if possible have a look at a queue/limiting library for goroutine: https://github.com/AnikHasibul/queue . If I were you, initially i will use this!

Comment: Why do you think it should be optimised, in the very first place?

Comment: @zerkms hi, thank you for your question, i think he need most control, for example, number of calls to the webservice, errors management, channels, task concurrently

Comment: This doesn't appear to be recursive as described.

Answer (score -1):

Not to be a jerk! But I would use a queue for this kind of things. I have already created a library and using this. github.com/AnikHasibul/queue

```
// Limit the max
maximumJobLimit := 50
// Open a new queue with the limit
q := queue.New(maximumJobLimit)
defer q.Close()

// simulate a large amount of jobs
for i := 0; i != 1000; i++ {
    // Add a job to queue
    q.Add()

    // Run your long long long job here in a goroutine
    go func(c int) {
        // Must call Done() after finishing the job
        defer q.Done()
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println(c)
    }(i)

}

//wait for the end of the all jobs
q.Wait()
// Done!
```